# If name is not match to sheet 2 from sheet 1 add name to sheet 2

Tags: excel, copy, match, vba

I have 2 sheets, one named bills and the other named sheet1.

I have VBA code to find the name and paste the information to the matching name, but how do I add a new name that is not there?

Then if name is not found, add name to bills column F row 192 and column F row 193.

example:

bills

```
A           B      C    D     E  F      G    H

xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  bill    xxx      
xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  bill    xxx 

xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  man     xxx

xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  man     xxx



sheet1

 A          B      

bill      19.23   
man       156.23
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet

Dim j As Long, i As Long, lastrow As Long

Set sh1 = Worksheets("test")

Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    lastrow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    lastrow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastrow1
        For j = 1 To lastrow2
            If sh1.Cells(i, "F").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "A").Value Then
                sh1.Cells(i, "H").Value = sh2.Cells(j, "B").Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you trying to make a Pivot Table? Could Excel's Pivot Table feature solve your problem without using a macro?

Comment: I need a macro because I am running others macro in a program that I made in C#

Comment: You could incorporate the pivot table into your macro. That seems to me to be the path of least resistance here.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're trying to use a macro and not to make this sound too simple but have you thought of just naming the desired range on the data entry sheet (bills) and then, on sheet1 where you want the data to display, using a lookup formula?

For example:

**Bills.xls**

A           B      C    D     E  F      G    H

xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  bill    xxx
xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  bill    xxx

xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  man     xxx

xxx        xxxx   xxx  xxx  xx  man     xxx

sheet1

A          B

bill      19.23
man       156.23

.... name the range of F1:F100 "NAMES"

Then, on sheet1.xls
in each cell of the desired output row (just copy/paste) and use data validation with the named range /// could be simply a formula stating =if('NAMES'$F$1<>"",'NAMES'$F$1,"")

...that is, if I am understanding your needs correctly.

Comment: the name get added every week and I need the to have a macro do the work to add the new name from sheet 1 to sheet 2 if not found in sheet 2